# How to print a part of a JSON string and store it in variable?

Tags: json, linux, shell, curl

I am using curl to create a session to log into the switch.
Below the script that i use

```
curl --noproxy 10.23.193.1 -X POST http://10.23.193.1:80/rest/v3/login-sessions -d '{"userName":"admin", "password":"password"}'
```

After this is executed I get the following output

```
{"uri":"/login-sessions","cookie":"sessionId=DfZNCFbfoc3LDuMgjLXRiS8ZmEo4MWENCOJM0Iu14R1uMT9kKqbe1Rx6AedmoeT"}
```

My requirement here is to first only print this part of the string `"sessionId=DfZNCFbfoc3LDuMgjLXRiS8ZmEo4MWENCOJM0Iu14R1uMT9kKqbe1Rx6AedmoeT"`

Secondly I would want to know how to store the above string in a variable so that I could call the same variable for subsequent operations

I ran  the following, but I am not getting any output.

```
curl --noproxy 10.23.193.1 -X POST http://10.23.193.1:80/rest/v3/login-sessions -d '{"userName":"admin", "password":"password"}' | grep -`E ""cookie":"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using simple tools like grep or sed to parse JSON as they won't handle things like quotes or multi-line data correctly. It's best to use a JSON-aware program such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

With jq it's simple and robust:

```
curl ... | jq '.cookie'
```

To store the cookie in a variable use the `-r` flag to have JQ print out the raw, unquoted string.

```
cookie=$(curl ... | jq -r '.cookie')
```

Further reading:

- [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)
- [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)
- [How to parse JSON with shell scripting in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux)

Comment: Thank you very much. You are awesome. Will figure out a way to install jq and go from there. Thank you loads